# ESLint "Unexpected tab character" when "indent" rule set to "tab"

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, indentation, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm using ESLint with the [Airbnb plugin (`eslint-config-airbnb`)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) and Babel parser. I've just added the extra rule of using <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters for indentation instead of spaces.

Here is my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "jsx-a11y",
        "import"
    ],
    "rules":{
        "indent": [2, "tab"]
    }
}
```

Now I get this error at every indentation:

```
Error: Unexpected tab character
```

Just in case it helps, I'm using Atom IDE with the autolinter plugins `linter` and `linter-eslint`.

Comment: Is there a stack trace that accompanies that error? It doesn't look to be a normal linter error, though it could be coming from the parser.

Comment: The error was being showed by atom, yes, it said something about no-tabs rule ;)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I answer myself, it was because Airbnb has set the rule `no-tabs` to 2 or error, I just disabled it.

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "jsx-a11y",
        "import"
    ],
    "rules":{
        "indent": [2, "tab"],
        "no-tabs": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, it happens for standard ones as well and not just airbnb and no-tab rule works. thanks

Comment: thanks! I had my indent rule set to tab but didn't know that I had to specifically disable airbnb's "no-tabs". It works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"no-tabs" rule looks for tabs anywhere inside a file: code, comments or anything else.
It may be a another answer.

```
...
"rules": {
    ...
    "no-tabs": ["error", { "allowIndentationTabs": true }]
    ...
}
...
```